# How to count the number of lines written by csv.writer?

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to keep track of the amount of lines that are being written by my csv.writer.

On running the code the `len(list(reader)` identifies the correct number of rows and if `under 100`, writer proceeds to insert 2 new rows, thats all good, but after the first loop `len(list(reader)` will always sum to 0 row causing an infinite loop. I assumed this was a memory problem since the writer seems to write to memory and flush to disk at the end but flushing the file or recreating reader instance doesn't help.

```
import csv
import time

row = [('test', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4'), ('testa', 'testb', 'testc', 'testd')]

with open('test.csv', 'r+', newline='') as csv_file:

    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    while True:
        # moved reader inside loop to recreate its instance had no effect
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=';')
        num = len(list(reader))
        if num <= 100:
            print(num)
            writer.writerows(row)
            csv_file.flush()  # flush() had no effect
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            print(num)
            break
```

How could I get the `len(list(reader)` to keep track of the files content at all times?

Answer (score -1):

I dont see the need to create the reader object in the loop where you're writing into the csv. What you can do is:

```
import csv
count = 0
li =[[1,2,3,4,5],[6,7,8,9,10]]
with open('random.csv','w') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in li:
        csv.writerow(row)

with open('random.csv','r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    global count
    for row in reader:
        if len(row) != 0:
            count += 1
```